# How to enable an UISwitch while disabling other two simultaneously

Tags: objective-c, xcode, if-statement, uiswitch

I have 3 UISwitches in my View Controller and each one identifies gender ("Woman, Male, No Gender") that user has to choose.

The behavior I would like to implement is that, when the user taps on a switch to select the gender, the others two have to be disabled simultaneously.
And once the switch is selected, the "Create Profile" button is activated. ([screenshots attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ypuou.png))

I'm not able to implement the if condition (or alternatively a switch condition)to do that.
Please help.

This is the code I implemented:

```
- (IBAction)checkGenderSwitch:(id)sender {
if ([self.femaleGenderSwitch isOn] && (![self.maleGenderSwitch isOn] && ![self.noGenderSwitch isOn])) {
    [self enableCreateProfileButton];
} else if ([self.maleGenderSwitch isOn] && (![self.femaleGenderSwitch isOn] && ![self.noGenderSwitch isOn])) {
    [self enableCreateProfileButton];
} else if ([self.noGenderSwitch isOn] && (![self.femaleGenderSwitch isOn] && ![self.maleGenderSwitch isOn])) {
    [self enableCreateProfileButton];
}else{
    [self disableCreateProfileButton];
    }
```

}

Thanks.

Comment: This is not an answer to your specific question, but I'd consider three switches the wrong interface for this. Mutually exclusive options are better handled by a segmented control or picker, or if you want to keep the vertically stacked layout, a three-row table view with a single selection state. Currently if your user chooses an incorrect item they have to switch off the option they chose before switching on the correct one? Why make them do that?

Comment: In fact this is exactly my problem. I need to keep the current layout allowing the user to enable only one switch, automatically disabling the other two without him doing it.

Comment: It sounds like you're saying "disable" (i.e. make the switch impossible to use) but what you actually mean is "turn off"?

Comment: Yes sorry. I mean "turn off".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's reformulate your need:

Every time you change a switch value, you do (in pseudo code):

```
if (male isOn && female isOff && noGender isOff) { enableButton }
else if (male isOff && female isOn && noGender isOff) { enableButton} 
else if (male isOff && female isOff && noGender isOn)) { enableButton } 
else { disableButton }
```

Which could be translated in:

```
if (onlyMale isOn) { enableButton }
else if (onlyFemale isOn) { enableButton} 
else if (onlyNoGender isOn) { enableButton } 
else { disableButton }
```

`only... isOn`? What about putting them into a `NSArray`, and count the number of `isOn`? That should do the trick no? `only... isOn` is for `count = 0 where isOn == true`.

Which could be then coded:

```
NSArray *switches = @[self.femaleGenderSwitch, self.maleGenderSwitch, self.noGenderSwitch];
NSUInteger numberOfSwitchesOn = 0;
for (UISwitch *aSwitch in switches) {
    if ([aSwitch isOn]) {
        numberOfSwitchesOn += 1;
    }
}

if (numberOfSwitchesOn == 1) {
    [self enableCreateProfileButton];
} else {
    [self disableCreateProfileButton];
}
```

Now, if you want that when you switchOn a Switch, you switchOff the other two (if needed), which in our case would only be one, it can be done with:

```
NSArray *switches = @[self.femaleGenderSwitch, self.maleGenderSwitch, self.noGenderSwitch];

BOOL hasASwitchOn = NO;

//We iterate over the switches
for (UISwitch *aSwitch in switches) {
    //If the newly set is set to on, we need to disable the other (the one which aren't the same as the sender)
    if ((UISwitch *)[sender isOn] && ![sender isEqual:aSwitch]) {
        [aSwitch setOn:NO];
        hasASwitchOn = YES;
    } else if ([aSwitch isOn]) { //Else, we still count the number of isOn
        hasASwitchOn = YES;
    }
}

if (hasASwitchOn) {
    [self enableCreateProfileButton];
} else {
    [self disableCreateProfileButton];
}
```

Comment: I've put the switches in an Array as you suggested (so the button is activated if only one switch is selected).
But when I try to implement the second part of the code, the for cycle let me enable only a switch and disable the others simultaneously, but I can't activate the button.

Comment: It work but when I press the button, the app crashes due to this error:


`int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}`

Thread 1: "-[UIButton isOn]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x105935ef0"

Comment: There should be an error in console. Which is it?

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIButton isOn]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x105935ef0'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: You have a UIButton somewhere, not a UISwitch. Which one is a UIButton and not a UISwitch? Or did you link also the button tap on that method?

Comment: Thank you! You solved my Problem!
I don't know why but when I linked the button to my code, Xcode automatically linked the button to this action.
I had to delete all links and repeat linking process.

Answer (score 0):

As has been said in a comment, the disablement requirement is wrong. All three switches need to be enabled at all times. The rule should be simply that only one switch at a time can be on.

The key here is that when you tap a switch, and the IBAction method is called, the `sender` is that switch.

So just keep a list references to all three switches and if the sender is now `on`, cycle thru the list and turn off each switch that is *not* the sender.

(Or use a three part UISegmentedControl which does all this for you automatically; it lets the user choose exactly one of three.)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `tag` property of `UIView` for your three switches, giving each of the three its own, unique tag value: for instance, 0, 1, 2. (You can set that up in Interface Builder, or in code — whichever you prefer.) This makes it trivial to distinguish the three switches.

Then, create one extra property, `genders`, an array of your three switches:

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UISwitch* femaleGenderSwitch;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UISwitch* maleGenderSwitch;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UISwitch* noGenderSwitch;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray* genders;
@end
```

In `-viewDidLoad` set that up:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.genders =
        @[[self femaleGenderSwitch], [self maleGenderSwitch], [self noGenderSwitch]];
}
```

Finally, you can simplify your logic in your action method like this:

```
- (IBAction)checkGenderSwitch:(id)sender
{
    if ([sender isOn]) {
        for (id aSwitch in [self genders]) {
            if ([aSwitch tag] != [sender tag]) {
                [aSwitch setOn:NO animated:YES];
            }
        }
        
        [self enableCreateProfileButton];
    }
    else {
        [self disableCreateProfileButton];
    }
}
```